# Multiple Django Projects using IIS but Getting Blank Page on Second Site

Tags: python, django, iis, wfastcgi

I'm running two django projects in IIS with wfastcgi enabled.  The first django project is running without an issue but the second project displays a blank page (code 200) returned.

Second Project Info:

A virtual folder, within it's own application pool in IIS, is created to host the second project.  The second project was created in an python environment folder.  The second project runs from django using python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080, but displays a blank page when browsing to the virtual folder page.

The root folder was granted with "everyone" full control access to all sub-folders
for the second project, wfastcgi application and handler is pointing to the virtual environment python and wfastcgi file correctly.

Can you have two wfastcgi applications and handlers "Second Python FastCGI"
C:\project_folder\project_env\Scripts\python.exe|C:\project_folder\project_env\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"

I wanted them separate so that two developers don't interfere with each others work, but they need to run within the same server and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by editing the web.config file and removing the static handler from it.  The static handler was being used instead of the FastCgiModule handler.  The static handler should be moved below the FastCgiModule.